# Remove leading zeros from a string using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am learning regex and java and working on a problem related to that.

I have an input string which can be any dollar amount like

```
$123,456.78
$0012,345.67
$123,04.56
$123,45.06
```

it also could be

```
$0.1
```

I am trying to find if the dollar amount has leading zeros and trying to remove it.

so far I have tried this

```
string result = input_string.replaceAll(("[!^0]+)" , "");
```

But I guess I'm doing something wrong.
I just want to remove the leading zeros, not the ones between the amount part and not the one in cents. And if the amount is $0.1, I don't want to remove it.

Comment: Use `.replaceFirst("(?<=\\$)0+(?=\\d)", "")` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/YhspqI/1))

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, that worked with all requirements! :)

Comment: @adamn2 except it doesn't work for `$0,012.34`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [`zeroes` is not a typo](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3825/12060)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match zeroes or commas that are preceded by a dollar sign and followed by a digit:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\$)[0,]+(?=\\d)", "");
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/CLof4LYunq7jPK).

This covers the edge cases:

- `$001.23` -> `$1.23`
- `$000.12` -> `$0.12`
- `$00,123.45` -> `$123.45`
- `$0,000,000.12` -> `$0.12`

The regex:

- `(?<=\\$)` means the preceding character is a dollar sign
- `(?=\\d)` means the following character is a digit
- `[0,]+` means one or more zeroes or commas

---

To handle *any* currency symbol:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=[^\\d,.])[0,]+(?=\\d)", "");
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/AniN0XuyQgMGJi).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```java
string result = input_string.replaceFirst("(?<=\\p{Sc})[0,]+(?=\\d)", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YhspqI/3).

*Details*:

- `(?<=\p{Sc})` - immediately on the left, there must be **any currency** char
- `[0,]+` - one or more zeros or commas
- `(?=\d)` - immediately on the right, there must be any one digit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple regex that fits your needs:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^[$][,0]+0(?![.])", "$");
```